# How can I specify the directory for puppet:///private/ when running 'puppet apply'?

Tags: puppet

So, I have a puppet repository. It's versioned with `git` and things like that. It would be convenient for me to be able to make tentative changes to a copy this repository on my machine, then try out the changes on a test computer, before committing these changes to the puppet server (avoiding the hassles of touching production machines for testing, and the hassle of puppetca signing a temporary EC2 instance). I can `scp` a copy of the repostory over to the appropriate machine and do `puppet apply site.pp --modulepath=foo --templatedir=blah`, and it mostly works...

until I have a file that's sourced from `puppet:///private/foo`. Then it's all `Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from source(s) puppet:///private/foo at /home/ubuntu/ops-puppet/production/modules/foobar/manifests/baz.pp:68`.

Is there a command line flag I can use to make to specify the path to the 'private' files? I can't seem to locate it in the documentation (but I might just be oblivious this morning ;)

Comment: Does the `private` directory exist with the proper permissions on the test server? Go and look in `/etc/puppet` or wherever you're putting the files to make sure that this error is not telling the truth. If the error is accurate, include the `/private` dir in your SCP (or just scp the entire `/etc/puppet` folder).

Comment: The repository is being rsynced to `/home/ubuntu/puppet`, not `/etc/puppet`. It would be really grand if I could find a solution to this which didn't involve hacking up /etc/puppet (per user @pwan below), since that's kinda tedious to do since I'm actually working with a couple of instances here (rsyncable things and pastable command line flags are ever so lovely) -- but if there isn't any I guess that's just something I'll have to cope with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your /etc/puppet/fileserver.conf file (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html#file-server-configuration) and make sure it has a [private] block that points to the expected directory.

Zac B's comments on the question about checking the permissions on the private directory are also a good idea.

Comment: Okay, I had to work at it but was able to turn this into a resolution. Since I was trying to `puppet apply` from a copy of a git repository living in `/home/ubuntu/puppet` for ease-of-rsync reasons, I had to go into /etc/puppet and symlink the puppet.conf, fileserver.conf, and `private` directories from that repository. (Symlinking the entire directory to `/etc/puppet` didn't work; I think the etckeeper hooks freaked out.) This actually stinks; I looked for a way to specify this with the command line but `--fsconfig` appears to be puppetmaster-only. Blegh.

Comment: Cheer up; you could always write a bash script to handle the creation of symlinks for you, and tear them down when you're done testing (or, if you're worried about forgetting the mess, you could tear them down via cron). Then you'd only have to run two commands to be tesing-ready: your scp, and then make_links.sh or what-have-you.

Comment: Another approach would be to switch to using a 'private' module and move your private files under /etc/puppet/modules/private/files, and change your source to puppet://modules/private/foo.  You will probably want to add a [modules] block to /etc/puppet/fileserver.conf so puppet will server files under the modules directory.